# Populate NSComboBox from Data Source

Tags: macos, swift2, nscombobox

This code compiles OK, but the ComboBox (cbxColors) is empty - not populated from the Data Source (array: COLORS_OF). `Uses Data Source` is checked in IB.

`func numberOfItemsInComboBox()`  returns the correct result: 5.

`func comboBox()`  is not doing its job.

What am I missing?

**EDITED:** Now working.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSComboBoxDelegate, NSComboBoxDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    cbxColors.dataSource = self

    numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell(cbxColors)
    comboBoxCell(cbxColors, objectValueForItemAtIndex: 0)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {

}

@IBOutlet weak var cbxColors: NSComboBox!
@IBOutlet weak var txtResult: NSTextField!


@IBAction func actColors(sender: NSComboBox) {
    // display User selected item in 'txtResult'
}

func numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell(aComboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
    return(COLORS_OF.count)
}

func comboBoxCell(aComboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAtIndex index: Int) -> AnyObject {
    return(COLORS_OF[index])
}

let COLORS_OF = [ "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow" ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not doing it's job"? Is your "cbxColors" IBoutlet correctly hooked and not nil? Why do you have "NSTextFieldCell" IBoutlet instead of "NSTextField" ?

Comment: @xhruso00 "cbxColors" IBOutlet is correctly hooked to the ComboBox in IB.  I changed "NSTextFieldCell! as suggested. I say "not doing its job" because the ComboBox is not getting populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to check Uses Data Source or you have to delete datasource connection and reconnect it again (weird bug of Xcode).

[image]

Other then that if your outlets are correctly hooked your code works.

[image]

Comment: As I stated, 'Uses Data Source' is checked.

Comment: Does your code stop on breakpoints (numberOfItems?) What OS X do you use? Can you attach sample project (works for me out of box so I will test if your project is OK).

Comment: The example now works. I added this statement:
    cbxColors.dataSource = self
and added 'Cell' to the two functions and calls.

Comment: This means you did not have all outlets hooked; namely datasource ;) Sometimes there is a bug in Xcode so you have to delete connection and reconnect.

Comment: Yes, that was the case.  When I deleted and reconnect the datasource I didn't need the code I added - it worked as I thought it should have.  If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I would be pleased to accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps other